# How to remove all items from main layout?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget

I have MainWindow with QWidget *mainWidget. This widget has setting layout - QLayout *mainLayout. When I will press button "Next" I want to clear mainLayout from all items (I need use mainLayout again but with diffrent items) and also when I will press button "Back" again, I need clear layout and use it with another items.

I tried use while loop with mainWidget->layout()->TakeAt(0) but it doesn't work (I think that I have problem with while loop because my mainLayout has a few columns and rows). I am begginer and I have problems with understand memory allocation etc.

Comment: You should look at QStackedLayout and QStackedWidget. If you need a widget with pages, QWizard would be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is what i need! you are my hero today :D

Answer (score 0):

Delete all widgets: they remove themselves from the layout automatically. You can also set a different layout on the main widget, then add new widgets to it. When moving to the previous page, set the previous layout on it. You’d have to manage the visibility of the widgets, though: they’d still be visible.

But none of this is necessary: each page should be its own widget, that you parent to the main widget when you wish it shown, and un-parent when it’s to be hidden. The main layout can then be anything simple, like `QVBoxLayout`, since it holds only one widget – the current page.

And then: are you sure there’s no widget or layout that supports pages of widgets? Look in the documentation, you may be pleasantly surprised :)